# How do I move the groupCursor parameters to the childCursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, expandablelistadapter

I not really sure if that is the correct title.  However,  what I need to do is add some sort of parameter to my getChildrenCursor so that it only shows the children for that particular group and not all of the children for each group. Sort like how getExtras work.

I am using Fragments and the ExpandabeListAdaptor extending the SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.  As I mentioned everything is working perfectly except that all children are loaded for each group.  I believe I have to map the ID for each group to its children but I am unsure how to do this.

I have seen this in a bunch of other code samples, but I am not sure how to implament it for my code.  Something like this I believe:

```
 Cursor childCursor = mDbHelper.fetchChildren(GroceryListMain.group,
            groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

That is the idea for what I think I need to do but I am not sure.
I am using only one database table.

My code to add items to the ExpandableListiew is this:

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;




public class JobOpportunities extends SherlockFragment{

 private JobDbAdaptor dbHelper;
 private MyExpandableListAdapter dataAdapter;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.jobmain, container, false);

 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      dbHelper = new JobDbAdaptor(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
      dbHelper.open();

      //Clean all data
      dbHelper.deleteAllJobs();
      //Add some data
      dbHelper.insertSomeJobs();


      //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
     displayListView();




 }//end of activity create

 private void displayListView() 
 {
     Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllJobs();

     ExpandableListView explist = (ExpandableListView)  getView().findViewById(R.id.expandList);

     dataAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(cursor, getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
             R.layout.job_info,
             R.layout.child_info,
             new String[] {JobDbAdaptor.KEY_NAME},
             new int[] {R.id.name},
             new String[] {JobDbAdaptor.KEY_DESCRIPTION, JobDbAdaptor.KEY_POSITION, JobDbAdaptor.KEY_LOCATION},
             new int[] {R.id.childitem1, R.id.childitem2, R.id.childitem3});

    explist.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

 }//end of list view

  public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter 
    {
        public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context jobOpportunities, int groupLayout,
                int childLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom,
                int[] childrenTo) {
            super(jobOpportunities, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childrenFrom,
                    childrenTo);
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor fetchGroup) 
        {
            // Given the group, we return a cursor for all the children within that group 


            fetchGroup = dbHelper.fetchchildren();

            return fetchGroup;

        }//end of childcursor

    }//end of myexpandable list adapter


}//end of jobopportunities
```

and this is my database code:

```
    package com.example.fragments;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class JobDbAdaptor {

   //field names
   public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
   public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
   public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
   public static final String KEY_POSITION = "postition";
   public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

  //variables
  private static final String TAG = "JobDbAdapter";
  private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
  private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

 //database info
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Opportunities";
 private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Job_Info";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 private final Context mCtx;

 //defines the fields and constraints
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
 "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
 KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
 KEY_NAME + "," +
 KEY_DESCRIPTION + "," +
 KEY_POSITION + "," +
 KEY_LOCATION + ");";

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
 {

 //constructor for database sets name and version
 DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
 {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }


 @Override//creates database
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
 {
   Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
   db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
 }

 @Override//checks for new version and overrides old
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
 {
  Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
  + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
  onCreate(db);
 }
 }//end of update

 public JobDbAdaptor(Context ctx)
 {
 this.mCtx = ctx;
 }

 //opens the database and sets the state
 public JobDbAdaptor open() throws SQLException 
 {
   mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
   mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();//state i.e. writable or readable
   return this;
   }

   //closes database
   public void close() 
  {

    if (mDbHelper != null) 
  {
    mDbHelper.close();
  }

  }

  //creates each job
  public long createJob(String name, String description,
  String position, String location) 
  {  

   ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
   initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
   initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
   initialValues.put(KEY_POSITION, position);
   initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);

   return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

  }//end of create jobs

  //deletes all of the jobs
  public boolean deleteAllJobs()
  {

    int doneDelete = 0;
    doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
    Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
    return doneDelete > 0;

  }//end of delete all jobs

  //searches the job based on input text
  public Cursor fetchJobsByName(String inputText) throws SQLException 
  {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
    mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_NAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_POSITION, KEY_LOCATION},
    null, null, null, null, null);

   }
    else 
   {
     mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
     KEY_NAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_POSITION, KEY_LOCATION},
     KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
     null, null, null, null);
   }
     if (mCursor != null) 
   {
     mCursor.moveToFirst();
   }

     return mCursor;

   }//end of fetchjobs by name

   //gets all of the jobs
   public Cursor fetchAllJobs() 
   {

     Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
     KEY_NAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_POSITION, KEY_LOCATION},
     null, null, null, null, null);

   if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
   }
   return mCursor;

   }//end of fetch all jobs

    //fetches the group headers or just the titles of the job
    public Cursor fetchgroup()
    {
   Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME}, null,
    null, null, null, null);

  if(mCursor != null)
 {
     mCursor.moveToFirst();

 }

 return mCursor;

     }//end of fetchgroups

     //fetches the the info for the children
     public Cursor fetchchildren()
     {
     Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_POSITION, KEY_LOCATION}, null,
    null, null, null, null);

 if(mCursor != null)
 {
     mCursor.moveToFirst();

 }

 return mCursor;

     }//end of fetchchildren

    //holds the content for each job
   public void insertSomeJobs()
   {

     createJob("AFG","Afghanistan","Asia","Southern and Central Asia");
     createJob("ALB","Albania","Europe","Southern Europe");
     createJob("DZA","Algeria","Africa","Northern Africa");
     createJob("ASM","American Samoa","Oceania","Polynesia");
     createJob("AND","Andorra","Europe","Southern Europe");
     createJob("AGO","Angola","Africa","Central Africa");
     createJob("AIA","Anguilla","North America","Caribbean");

   }//end of insertjobs

  }//end of JobDbAdaptor
```

I know it is something stupid that I am just not getting.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL I knew it was something stupid.

Here is the new getChildrenCursor:

```
 @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor fetchGroup) 
        {
            // Given the group, we return a cursor for all the children within that group 

            String dbcolumnId = JobDbAdaptor.KEY_NAME;
            Cursor fetchchild=dbHelper.fetchchildren(fetchGroup.getString(fetchGroup.getColumnIndex(dbcolumnId)));

            return fetchchild;


        }//end of childcursor
```

So I had to set it to read the value from the group, which I knew I had to but was not sure how to.  This sets the children based on the group, however it only pulls it form one table.  So when clicked the group only shows the children that it should.

Here is the Cursor method in the database, it was modifidy to accpet the new values:

```
 public Cursor fetchchildren(String dbcolumnId )
{
 Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_POSITION, KEY_LOCATION}, KEY_NAME + "='" + dbcolumnId + "'",
    null, null, null, null);

 if(mCursor != null)
 {
     mCursor.moveToFirst();

 }

 return mCursor;

}//end of fetchchildren
```

This does not prevent SQL injection, but I am not having the using input anything here.